# Android app crash (web_view)

Tags: java, webview, crash

So Every time i try to run my app, it crashes.  Their are no errors in the code. 
Its just a simple webview app.  But when i run it in the eumlator, i get these errors in the logcat.  I tried to look for soultions, but cant find any.  I just cant figured out why it keeps crashing. I made a app just like this before, with the same code and had no errors. So i went back and compared the two code, and their the same.  I dont know if its a error with android studio, becuase i did update my android studio.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KXLQ.png

These is the logcat

Comment: **'You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.'**... Update your AndroidManifest.xml to use the `Theme.AppCompat` theme.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at your android manifest file and make sure that the android theme you are using in the webview or app is Theme.AppCompat or a descendant of Theme.AppCompat. This is a weird issue but its happened to me before and I changed the theme to comply with what the error message was telling me, and it worked.

Comment: I changed the theme, but now i get 5 new errors and the webview wont work in the app.  Here are the errors. E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.      E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.                   E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.                                                  E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.                       E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff()failed